# Split a long one line of json file into multilines

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to split a one line JSON file into a multiliner, after every comma.

I've tried using the the split method, but it is still not the output I'm looking for. This is how far ive come so far.

```py
with open('api.txt', 'w+') as f : 
        api = res.read().decode('utf-8')
        f.write(api)

        new_api = str(api).split(",")
        with open('new_api.txt', 'w+') as n : 
            n.write(new_api)
```

I would like a result like this:

line1"language":null

line2"has_issues":true
line3"has_projects":true
line4"has_downloads":true
line5"has_wiki":true
line6 "has_pages":false

Comment: add sample of your `one line JSON`

Comment: Please give us an example of a piece of input and the corresponding output you want for it - not just the output :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and adding the .join to your method.
After declaring the new_api.

Like this:

```
with open('api.txt', 'w+') as f : 
    api = res.read().decode('utf-8')
    f.write(api)

    new_api = str(api).split(",")

    new_api = "\n".join(["".join(new_api[i:i+1]) for i in range(0,len(new_api))])
```

This will split you comma, and even decode your line, from the beginning to the end of the comma. Let me know if this solved your problem.

Comment: I have been looking at this for hours! you really helped me! I'm still new to python, so I didnt know you can add another .join, and even  a for loop at the same time! Thank you

Comment: Glad I can help :-)